# List with two different designs for odd/even items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-arrayadapter

Suppose we have two different list item designs.

I want the list items that appear at odd positions to have the first design, and those that appear at even positions to have the second design.

It it possible to achieve this goal using two XML files and only one single ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 0):

> To customize the appearance of each item you can override the
>   toString() method for the objects in your array. Or, to create a view
>   for each item that's something other than a TextView (for example, if
>   you want an ImageView for each array item), extend the ArrayAdapter
>   class and override getView() to return the type of view you want for
>   each item.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout#AdapterViews

Personally I'd just use a recyclerView.Adapter and you can do that fairly easily with those, tons of examples out there.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through elements of an array and inflate different layouts depending on the index like this (in Kotlin):

```
for ((i, item) in list.withIndex()){
    val row = if (i % 2 == 0) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate() // inflate layout 1
    else LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate() // inflate layout 2

    ...

    listView.addView(row)
}
```

where layout 1 and layout 2 are xmls of your 2 designs

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You just need to inflate layout depending on position (even/odd).
In getView() method of your arrayadapter, do this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        if (position % 2 == 0) {  //  is even
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.even_layout, parent, false);

        } else {    //  is odd
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.odd_layout, parent, false);
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}
```